# UIPasteboard multiple items don't paste completely

Tags: ios, copy-paste, uipasteboard

Here is the code, I copy text and image to UIPasteboard with

```
@IBAction func btnCopyDidPress(_ sender: Any) {
    let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
    var items: [[String: Any]] = [[kUTTypeUTF8PlainText as String: "here goes some text"]]
    if let image = UIImage(named: "some_image"), let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
        items.append([kUTTypeJPEG as String: imageData])
    }
    pasteboard.items = items
}
```

When I try then to paste it to Notes app or Gmail app it's all ok - both parts are pasted. The exception is standard Mail app by Apple. Only image part pastes. If I comment `items.append([kUTTypeJPEG as String: imageData])` then I can see text part is pasting to Mail app new message draft (and no image of course). I tried a couple of ideas (use PNG representation or reduce image resolution, append image before text) but they all failed.